# IE6/7 doesn't render html br tag

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to separate each word with a newline in HTML/JS and IE6 and IE7 refuse to render the br tag, instead I get all in one line.

Here's the JS code:
http://jsbin.com/atodur/edit#source

Is there any solution or workaround to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Easy fix, don't support IE 6/7, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the code is not going into the else since `word[i]` is undefined.

change

```
if (word[i] != " ")
```

to

```
if (word.charAt(i) != " ")
```

Basic Info:

- `word[i]` is non standard way of access the characters of a string.
- `charAt()` is the standard way

String Character Access [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)

Comment: @James Hay - That's a jsbin, not a fiddle, and what's the supposed to show me that the OP's jsbin doesn't?

Comment: 'Array-like character access [...] is not part of ECMAScript 3. It is a JavaScript and ECMAScript 5 feature.' [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: @j08691 You're right, it is. It just shows the changes that epascarello answered with, which is why it's a comment on his answer.

Comment: Thank you!
I played with this problem for some time and turns out to be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I might misunderstand here, but is the desired output:

```
Hello<br/>world
```

If so, can't you do like this?

```
canvas.innerHTML = word.replace(' ','<br/>');
```